# Get the number of orders with status 'processing'

Tags: api, order-status

I am trying to get the number of orders with status 'processing' and below is the code.

```
$countProcessingOrders = 0;    

$processingOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at');

foreach ($processingOrders as $order) {
        $countProcessingOrders++; 
}
```

For some reason, the (count) output compared to Magento Admin is off by one.
It would be helpful if anyone can give clues as to why this may occur?

Note: I am selecting the 'created_at' attribute for some other purpose.

Comment: If you're running this in a one-off script, make sure to set the default timezone first.

Comment: Have a look at the collections ```getSize()``` method as compared to ```count()``` or manual looping if you don't need the collection items otherwise. It is much more efficient.

Comment: @philwinkle Atleast for this question, the timezone doesn't matter because I am not using the 'created_at' attribute in this case. I just want to get the count of orders in 'processing' status.

Comment: @Vinai if I can get the count right first then, I would be happy to optimize the code.

Comment: Use ```Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)->getSize()```

Comment: @Vinai Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)->getSize() has the same result as the code in my question. The result is still off by 1. To add context, the count returned by the API is one more than the number displayed in Magento Admin.

Comment: Same result but a lot faster.

Comment: @Vinai so back to the original question, any clue as to why the count is off by one?

Comment: Does the discrepancy also happen with other filters, or only with the status? What does ```Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()``` return in your script?

Comment: @Vinai 1. At this point, I think it's an issue with a custom extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
$processingOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING) //use state instead of status since 'processing' is a state of the order not a status.
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at');
$total = $processingOrders->count();
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've change the answer. I modified `addFilter` to `addFieldToFilter`

Comment: Using 'state' instead of 'status' doesn't seem to help. The count is way off compared to the count in Magento Admin.

Comment: Modifying addFilter to addFieldToFilter has the same result as using 'state' instead of 'status'. Both of these don't return the expected count (the count displayed in Magento Admin being the expected result).

Answer (score 1):

Magento admin backend uses sales_flat_order_grid table. Try use this one:

```
$processingOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_grid')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at');
$total = $processingOrders->count();
```